# Is something am i missing while creating an React app?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have created a react app and when I run it shows the following errors. Firstly I thought I made a mistake while creating the app. After that, I have deleted it and created another app and it shows the same errors!

```
events.js:200
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)     
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
errno: 'ENOENT',
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn cmd',
path: 'cmd',
spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fruit_details@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fruit_details@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-09T06_29_21_939Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is a problem with react-scripts. Simply go to your folder in command and reinstall using following command this:

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```